# Как получить данные из указателя на массив указателей?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

У меня есть 2 массива, я сохраняю их в массиве указателей

```
float arrX[] = {...}, arrY[] = {...};
float* point[2];
point[0] = arrX;
point[1] = arrY;
```

После этого я создаю указатель на массив указателей и возвращаю его из функции

```
float** res = point;
return res;
```

После этого мне нужно получить значения, содержащиеся в массивах arrX,arrY в функции,получившей указатель res. Все перепробовал, но так и не смог этого сделать. Подскажите решение этой проблемы. Так же подойдет другой вариант, с помощью которого можно вернуть из функции два массива или двумерный массив

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Просто так](https://ideone.com/WNEOpX)?

```
    float** res = point;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) cout << res[i][j] << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Но вы точно не возвращаете указатель на *локальные массивы* - иначе кто же вам доктор?...

Comment: вопрос  элементарный, но плюсую имеено за последнюю фразу